# Nikon D3 Playback and Delete acting strange

Tags: nikon

Been using my D3 for years now.  On Thursday night, I was shooting some product inventory for a local business and when I went to review a few of my first photos, noticed that I was scrolling through each photo twice.  I've got two memory cards in my D3, and the second card is set to Backup mode.  But all of a sudden, playback is showing me each picture from each card.  Something it has never done before.

Additionally, Deleting a photo is working exactly the same way.  Whereas deleting a photo prior to Thursday night would delete it off of both cards, now it's deleting off of only 1 card, forcing me to delete each photo twice.

I've not updated any firmware or fundamentally changed anything about my hardware, and I didn't change anything deliberately in my settings (clearly I must have, but it must have been accidental).  I've spent the last 45 minutes going through the D3 manual, looking online, and working my way through the D3s menus and I can't find an answer to this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Double check that you're still set to **Backup** in your card setup...

**Reformat** both memory cards...

When you're in **Playback** I think there is a different menu. Check the **Playback Folder** setting- the default is **NCD3S** but if it's set to something else it may be causing what you're seeing.

If all else fails, you can do a **Two Button Reset** and start over from scratch... **Save** your settings so you can reload them after the reset, but see if the reset fixes the problem first.